# React Native Obfuscation and Hermes

Tags: react-native, obfuscation, react-native-hermes

I have been using [react-native-obfuscating-transformer](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/react-native-obfuscating-transformer) to obfuscate the JavaScript side of the react-native. However, now I am planning to use [Hermes](https://github.com/facebook/hermes). I was wondering if obfuscation is recommended on top of Hermes as it compiles JavaScript to bytecode during build time.

Answer (score 1):

Hermes doesn't compile the assets/index.android.bundle in your APK, which is what react-native-obfuscating-transformer claims to do. So they indeed do different things. Were you able to successfully obfuscate the assets/index.android.bundle in your apk with react-native-obfuscating-transformer? Most (perhaps all?) developers have found it unsuccessful.

Comment: when using Hermes, `assets/index.android.bundle` is complied to binary. though you are right about the obfuscating-transformer. it did not obfuscate the `assets/index.android.bundle`.